# E: Unable to locate package lamp-server

Tags: lamp

I am trying to install lamp server in ubuntu 13.10. But it gives the following error.

```
E: Unable to locate package lamp-server
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is not the correct command.

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

Comment: That worked.. Before that I was trying apt-get which didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

To install LAMP server, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Comment: That's indeed the command recommended by the documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP First time I tried I forgot the `^` at the end and thus got the same error as asker.